# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DIXLogger' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-packaging

I am facing an package import issue in Python 3.10. This is my folder structure:

```
MainProjectDIX
|___DIXLogger
|   |_____init__.py
|   |___dix_logger.py
|___Infra
|   |_____init__.py
|   |_____main__.py
|   |___my_class.py
```

I am trying to import DIXLogger from within `__main__.py`, but getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DIXLogger'
```

This is the import statement inside `__main__.py`:

```
from DIXLogger.dix_logger import DIXComLogger
```

Comment: How/what are you running your script/package? What is the code that is importing the `__main__` module?

Comment: I see no `__init__.py` file in the `MainProjectDIX` folder. That suggests it is not a Python package, and `DIXLogger` and `Infra` are separate Python packages. From where are you running things, and what is your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: As currently is, that single import line can work fine. We'll need more information; see my two comments above.